# How to run several Kotlin coroutines in parallel and wait for them to complete before proceeding

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to run 2 coroutines in parallel and wait for them to finish before proceeding. The code below works but it uses `GlobalScope` which is not the best way to do it.

Is there a better way?

```
fun getInfo(onSuccess: () -> Unit, onError: () -> Unit) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                coroutineScope {
                    launch { getOne() }
                    launch { getTwo() }
                }
                onSuccess.invoke()
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                onError.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would suggest implementing `getInfo` as a suspend function which knows the context it is supposed to run on. This way it does not matter from which context you invoke it (*).

Additionally, I would not use callbacks to proceed afterwards. 
You can just decide from what `getInfo()` returns on how to proceed (**).

This is actually the greatest thing about coroutines, you can turn callback based code in code that reads like sequential code.

Since you don't care for the result of `getOne()` and `getTwo()`, using `launch` is the correct way. It returns a `Job`. You can suspend the coroutine until both functions are finished with `joinAll()` which can be invoked on `Collection<Job>`.

```
suspend fun getInfo() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        listOf(
            launch { getOne() },
            launch { getTwo() }
        ).joinAll()
        false
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        true
    }
}
```

You don't need to use `GlobalScope`, just create your own (***).

I used `Default` as context to launch `getInfo`, but any other context would be fine too, since `getInfo` will run on the one it is supposed to.

```
val newScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
    val error = getInfo()
    if(error) {
        onSuccess()
    } else {
        onError()
    }
}
// "newScope" can be cancelled any time
```

---

<sub>* In case I used `Dispatcher.IO` to pretend that the two functions are doing some long running IO work.</sub>

<sub>** I used a simple boolean here, but of course you can return something more meaningful.</sub>

<sub>*** or hook into some scope given by the sourrouding framework which is lifecycle-aware</sub>

Comment: Thanks, great answer and I like your idea of making it return boolean.

Comment: If you create your own `CoroutineScope`, make sure to cancel it at some point. Otherwise just use `GlobalScope`.

Comment: @DominicFischer A GlobalScope will also exist until the application is terminated. So, you need to take care of integrating your scopes in your application's lifecycle but what that is depends on the kind of application, I even mention that "or hook into some scope given by the sourrouding framework which is lifecycle-aware"

Answer (score 5):

You can use any scope you like. That doesn't affect your question. GlobalScope is discouraged because it doesn't encapsulate your tasks.

Which scope to actually use to launch your coroutine is going to depend entirely on the context of what you're doing and what strategy of encapsulation you're using.

To launch multiple coroutines at once and wait for all of them, you use `async` and `await()`. You can use `awaitAll()` on a list of them if you simply need all of them to finish before continuing.

It seems odd that you use the IO dispatcher to run your callbacks on, but I'll leave that because I'm blind to the context of your code.

```
fun getInfo(onSuccess: () -> Unit, onError: () -> Unit) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                coroutineScope {
                    listOf(
                        async { getOne() }
                        async { getTwo() }
                    }.awaitAll()
                }
                onSuccess.invoke()
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                onError.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `CoroutineScope` inside the class you're working on and build coroutines just by calling `launch` builder. Something like this:

```
class MyClass: CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) { // or [by MainScope()]

    fun getInfo(onSuccess: () -> Unit, onError: () -> Unit) {
        launch {
            try {
                val jobA = launch { getOne() }
                val jobB = launch { getTwo() }
                joinAll(jobA, jobB)
                onSuccess.invoke()
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                onError.invoke()
            }
        }
    }

    fun clear() { // Call this method properly
        this.cancel()
    }

}
```

Make sure to cancel any coroutine running inside the scope by calling `cancel` properly.

Or if you're working inside a ViewModel just use the `viewModelScope` instead.

Comment: I don't believe your example would work, since the parent `CoroutineScope` doesn't actually contain a job. You'd need to manually add it in addition to `Dispatchers.IO`

Comment: @Kiskae Actually it works, I'm creating the scope using delegation as the official documentation states [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#coroutine-scope).

Comment: @GlennSandoval why wrapping a class around it? Just to get your own scope? I think that is a bit much.

Comment: @WilliMentzel. I'm assuming he's working inside a class and he's looking for an alternative to `GlobalScope.launch`, so I'm showing how to build a scope for that class. That's why I suggested if he's working inside a ViewModel then he should use the `viewModelScope` instead.

Comment: @GlennSandoval what you are proposing is correct, but for this case too much. it just makes too much (unnecessary) assumptions. we don't know whether getInfo is inside a class and that we are dealing with an android app and that's not the point of the question. don't take it the wrong way!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is even a better way based on the accepted answer:

```
suspend fun getInfo() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
try {
    coroutineScope {
        launch { getOne() }
        launch { getTwo() }
    }
    false
} catch (e: Throwable) {
    true
}
```

}